# C# wpf how to transfer data from datagrid to excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, datagrid

I've got little problem, with transferring data via copy and paste from datagrid to excel.

Especially from my user control, which I'm using in one datagrid column. Text columns are okay.

I got this code for copy row.

```
/// <summary>
/// Method which will copy entire row.
/// </summary>
private void CopyRow(object obj)
{
    var datagrid = obj as System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid;
    var currentRow = datagrid.SelectedIndex + 1;

    Dictionary<ENotifiedTruckFlags, string> transf = new Dictionary<ENotifiedTruckFlags, string>();
    string value = "";

    foreach (var e in _entityEnhancedNotifiedTruck.EFlags)
    {
        switch (e)
        {
            case ENotifiedTruckFlags.CheckRecordHasBreak:
                value = "Ridic má narízenou prestávku";
                break;
            case ENotifiedTruckFlags.CheckWeighingOn:
                value = "Režim kontrolního vážení";
                break;
            case ENotifiedTruckFlags.NoTaraWeighted:
                value = "Chybí tárové vážení";
                break;
            case ENotifiedTruckFlags.SPZProblem:
                value = "Provedte kontrolu SPZ";
                break;
            case ENotifiedTruckFlags.TimeProblem:
                value = "Provedte kontrolu ložné plochy";
                break;
        }
        transf.Add(e, value);
    }

    var myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<ENotifiedTruckFlags, string> pair in transf)
    {
        myStringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}", pair.Value);
        myStringBuilder.Append("," + " ");
    }

    datagrid.SelectAllCells();
    datagrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.ExcludeHeader;
    ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, datagrid);
    string result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
    datagrid.UnselectAllCells();
    Clipboard.SetText($"{result}\t{myStringBuilder}\t ");
}
```

Result parameter will result my text columns side to side perfectly, but in my string builder I have my user control and the text from it it give under on new line, but I want to have this particular text adjacent to result, not in new line.

Thanks.

Comment: Why use copy/paste instead of creating an actual Excel file with a library like EPPlus? Or use Office Interop to write directly to the sheet's cells?

Comment: Any tut for EPPlus?

Comment: [EPPlus Wiki](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki)